# How to sort an array using the substring of another array's values

Tags: php, arrays, string, sorting, matching

I have something like a vocabulary list with every vocabulary containing a number and the word. I have the same list of vocabulary but unsorted and in another language, the numbers match the meaning. So the same word has in both languages the same number. How can I match both vocabularys together and being in the same order of the main language? Example:

```
Input:
English Array (sorted)    German Array (unsorted)
74 Apple                  6 Auto
6 car                     564 Zug       
564 train                 74 Apfel

Output: the German Array is sorted in the same way as the English Array

74 Apple                  74 Apfel
6 car                     6 Auto      
564 train                 564 Zug
```

Help is much appreciated. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inputs:

```
$english = ["74 Apple", "6 car", "564 train"];
$german = ["6 Auto", "564 Zug", "74 Apfel"];
```

First, create an array with keys in the desired order:

```
array_map(
    function($v) use (&$sorting_keys) {
        return $sorting_keys[substr($v, 0, strpos($v, ' '))] = '';
    },
    $english
);
//var_export($sorting_keys);
// array (
//     74 => '',
//     6 => '',
//     564 => '',
// )
```

Next, reassign keys to the german array elements based on the leading id number

```
array_map(
    function($v) use (&$keyed_german) {
        return $keyed_german[substr($v, 0, strpos($v, ' '))] = $v;
    },
    $german
);
//var_export($keyed_german);
// array (
//     6 => '6 Auto',
//     564 => '564 Zug',
//     74 => '74 Apfel',
// )
```

Finally, transfer the values from `$keyed_german` to `$sorting_keys` (and reset the keys if you wish with `array_values()`):

```
$sorted_german = array_values(
    array_replace($sorting_keys, $keyed_german)
);
var_export($sorted_german);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => '74 Apfel',
  1 => '6 Auto',
  2 => '564 Zug',
)
```

---

Revisiting this answer years later, here is a cleaner, functional-styled solution with no temporary variables.  ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/eYjJ7))

```
var_export(
    array_values(
        array_replace(
            array_flip(
                array_map('intval', $english)
            ),
            array_reduce(
                $german,
                function($result, $value) {
                    $result[intval($value)] = $value;
                    return $result;
                }
            )
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: That's almost what i wanted. Maybe I didn't clarified it good enough. I want that the order of the words in the main language stays the same. So I only want to change the order of the translated language to match my main language. Like in my example, the list of words in english doesn't get changed, only the german words are arranged in a way to match the english words.

Comment: First of all, thank you very much for your help, i really appreciate it. I will definetely give you the green tick.

Comment: My english isnt the best, so I may explained it wrongly. My initial Plan was that I have an array for all the english words, but already sorted in my way. The numbering isn't consecutive. So the first word in the array may have the number 213 and the second word has the number 12. I want the german array (unsorted) to have the same order as the english array, pretty much like the example i have given. The numbering in both array is pretty random.

Comment: Yeah that was my fault, sorry for that. I edited it now :)

Comment: Thank you, thats it! The order and numbering is unfortunately crucial for me. Thank you again and have a great day :)